# How can I get glibc as a static library?

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to compile a program and statically link it to glibc, so it can run on other Linux distributions without the user having to do any special configuration.

I tried using `CFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc"`, but it statically links against all other libraries required, except glibc. I tried searching the apt repositories for a static version of glibc, but I couldn't find any.

I am using the default `gcc` installed with Ubuntu.

How can I get a static library version of glibc on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static version located in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a`

If not exists, type `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` or `sudo apt-get install glibc-static`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package glibc-static